# How to fix Xcode Organizer hanged at "Installing team provisioning profile"?

Tags: iphone, xcode

XCode 3.2.5 Organizer hanged when I try to "Use for Development" a Touch (2nd Generation), for over 30 mins:

[image]

If I try to quit, it shows a warning:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you considered rebooting your device and mac?

Comment: I have rebooted the device and retry the process. There's no more error. Not sure what caused the first hang-up though ... thx!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just unplug the device and plug it back in.

It will probably complain about not having the debug symbols or the software image for its OS version and offer to get the necessary info from the device. Accept, and a couple of minutes later you should see the green light for the device in the organizer.

No need to reboot anything or even restart XCode.